# How to regenerate target folder on Maven 'package'?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My project compiled folder is `/project/target/appname-0.24-SNAPSHOT/`, which will 
will result in `appname-0.24-SNAPSHOT.war` on `mvn package`.

How can I clean/regenerate this specific target folder before packaging?

I cannot execute `mvn clean` as this would clear the whole `target` folder, which I'd like to prevent because it contains lots of auto-generated webservice classes, which then in turn also would have to be regenerated and take a lot of time.

I'd only like to regenerate my project resources in `${project.build.directory}`. Is that possible?

maven config:

```
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>target</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>generated/*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>classes/*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
```

Comment: do you have a nested structure of `pom.xml` files, try running the `mvn package` command only for a specific module.

Comment: no I just have a single project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that using the `maven-clean-plugin` with a combination of

- `excludeDefaultDirectories` to stop it from deleting the whole directory
- `filesets` to tell it what to delete

ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html

Comment: Edited my question with clean config. But somehow, the excluding folders remain there, but their content is removed!

Comment: are you using the `boolean flag excludeDefaultDirectories` to first disable the deletion of all default output directory for the project?